# OnClick method on Android Studio is not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to show a message using a toast when you click one button. I did one OnClick ethod, but I don't know why is not executing when I click on the button.

MainActivit.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.i("OnCreat", "OnCreate method has been executed");
 }



   // Metodo listener para los botones (en este caso el boton Aplica)
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.i("startMethod", "method has startes");
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "botosi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i("showToast", "toast should been displayed");
}


}
```

Comment: it is just basics, you declared click listener, but you forgot to attach it to any view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initialize your button in your onCreate() something like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.i("OnCreate", "OnCreate method has been executed");

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButtonIdInXML);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

But before ask here any question, please read some documentation on https://developer.android.com, this is just a basic question.

Comment: thank you, you resolved my problem. I 'm sorry I'm just a newbie

Comment: @cobogarciaj accept the answer if it solved the problem. P.s. trust me, search on the site i linked to, it will be very useful for you if you are "just a newbie"